# picking specific ttyUSBx of a device

Tags: shell-script, ttyusb

I'm trying to improve a script to connect my cellular modem in Debian Linux.  This modem enumerates 5 USB ports and I need to use specific ones for specific purposes(One for initiating the data connection, one to query statistics such as signal strength). The original script file manually selects /dev/ttyUSB3 to connect, but when other USB devices are attached, they occasionally take precedence as ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1, which moves the cell modem tty ports up so that I may need to use ttyUSB4 or ttyUSB5 depending on whether those other devices are present.  Leaving the port static causes the scripts to fail in some instances.

With lsusb,

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2c7c:0121
```

I can see that the modem is bus 001 Device 006 ID: 2c7c:0121
and with udevadm info I can manually filter the attributes for each ttyUSB to see which device is on what port..

```bsh
echo `udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB3 --attribute-walk | sed -n 's/\s*ATTRS{\(\(devnum\)\|\(busnum\)\)}==\"\([^\"]\+\)\"/\1\ \4/p' | head -n 2 | awk '{$1 = sprintf("%s:%03d",$1,$2);print $1;}'` | tr " " "/"
```

gives me

```
busnum:001/devnum:006
```

manually changing ttyUSB4 to other ports shows me which other devices are on each port..
I found and tweaked another script, but keep getting odd issues that prevent it from running as intended. 
Here's my current script

```
#!/bin/bash
myport=0
for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
  (
    syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
    devname="$(udevadm  info -q name -p $syspath)" 
    [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && continue
    eval "$udevadm -]info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
    if [ "$ID_VENDOR_ID" == '2c7c' ]; then
      echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_VENDORID:$ID_MODEL_ID"
      myport= `expr $myport + 1 `
      if [ $myport == 3 ]
      then
        echo $port
        port= "/dev/$devname"
      fi
    fi
  )
if [ -z $port ]
then
  echo $port
fi
done
```

when I run the script, it properly filters out just the devices matching VID 2c7c but for some reason, I can't increment myport within the for loop
It goes from 0 to 1 but seems to reset to 0 each iteration and increment back to 1.
output looks like

```
/dev/ttyUSB0 - 2c7c:0121
1
/dev/ttyUSB1 - 2c7c:0121
1
/dev/ttyUSB2 - 2c7c:0121
1
/dev/ttyUSB3 - 2c7c:0121
1
/dev/ttyUSB4 - 2c7c:0121
1
```

If I do this above the for loop, it works as intended

```
x=0
x=`expr $x + 1 `
x=`expr $x + 1 `
x=`expr $x + 1`
echo $x
```

will output "3"

What do I need to do so I can properly count up to 3 and spit out the associated /dev/ttyUSB device at that point?

Comment: For one, there is a typo in your `myport=` statement: There must be no space behind the `= ` in shell variable assignments. Also, a more elegant formulation would be `myport=$((myport++))`. In addition, I would strongly encourage you to always quote your shell variables, and use the proper tests for numerical comparisons (i.e. `if [ "$myport" -eq 3 ]`).

Comment: tl;dr; you should either create a udev rule that adds a symlink named as you see fit, or use the `/dev/serial/by-id/*` files instead of `/dev/ttyUSB*`.

Comment: Even making the changes above, it looks like the real problem is the variable incremented in the subshell isn't preserved during each operation.  But I wasn't knowledgeable enough to recognize that.  Still revising to come up with a workable solution..